# Does Spalding have different versions of TF-1000? If so, what are the differences?

Tags: equipment, basketball

I have been looking for a replacement basketball, and thought of getting the new Euroleague ball, which Euroleague [sells from its official store](http://www.euroleaguestore.net/other-articles/spalding/euroleague-official-ball-spalding-tf-1000.html) for 80€.

[image]

What's interesting is that this ball has the same model name TF-1000 as one of Spalding's [regular balls](http://shop.spalding.com/Spalding-TF-1000-Classic-Basketball-29-5/dp/B00IPNQEYK?field_availability=-2&field_browse=5675135011&id=Spalding%20TF-1000%20Classic%20Basketball%2029%205&ie=UTF8&refinementHistory=subjectbin%2Cprice&searchNodeID=5675135011&searchPage=1&searchRank=salesrank&searchSize=12), which you can get in multiple varieties (Classic, Legacy, etc) for a wide variety of prices [from Amazon Germany](http://www.amazon.de/s/ref=sr_nr_p_n_feature_keywords_0?fst=as%3Aoff&rh=n%3A16435051%2Cn%3A%2116435121%2Cn%3A190418011%2Cn%3A191014011%2Ck%3Aspalding%20tf-1000&bbn=191014011&keywords=spalding%20tf-1000&ie=UTF8&qid=1429866467).

Does anyone know the differences between the Euroleague, Classic, and Legacy versions of this ball?